# Amazon EC2 (AWS) equivalent metrics for "Inbound Flows" metrics in Azure VM

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure-vm-scale-set, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Azure provides "`Inbound Flows`" (incoming live connections to `VM`) metrics at `VM` level and allows autoscaling based on that. Is there a similar metrics in `AWS` `EC2` level as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Azure and what this metric is, but if you deploy CloudWatch agent to your instance, you can get a bunch of new metrics: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html

Among them are:

> **netstat_tcp_established** - *The number of TCP connections established.*
>
> **netstat_udp_socket** - *The number of current UDP connections.*